# Android music player with lyrics Crashed when replaying

Tags: java, android

I created a project called "MusicMod" on Google Code (Based on eliot stocker's Music Mod.) http://code.google.com/p/musicmod/

Screenshot is available on project page

It can shows lyrics when playing, but crashes when replaying (Sometimes also crashes when k/b pulls out, etc.)
Below is My error log:

```
W/dalvikvm( 6065): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6065): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
E/AndroidRuntime( 6065): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 6065):    at com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector$1$1.run(MediaConnector.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6065):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
W/ActivityManager(  100):   Force finishing activity com.googlecode.musicmod/.MediaPlaybackActivity
E/ActivityThread( 6065): Activity com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaPlaybackActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector$MediaPlayerServiceConnection@43650b18 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread( 6065): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaPlaybackActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector$MediaPlayerServiceConnection@43650b18 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector.bindToMusicService(MediaConnector.java:87)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector.<init>(MediaConnector.java:48)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaPlaybackActivity.onCreate(MediaPlaybackActivity.java:138)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/ActivityThread( 6065):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  100): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@439c5a70
I/Process ( 6065): Sending signal. PID: 6065 SIG: 9
```

You can also view my source code in my project page.
If you can solve this, I can add you as comitter of this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure regarding that, but it seems that `getLyricsContext` might return null, and you don't check for it in lines 64-65 of `MediaConnector`.

Three adiitional things:

1. when you see at the stack trace a line like this: `com.googlecode.musicmod.MediaConnector$1$1.run(MediaConnector.java:65)` the `$1` refers to an anonymous  class. `MediaConnector$1$1` means an anonymous class in an anonymous class in MediaConnector.
2. You have the exact line where it happens, and you have the exception, it should not be too hard to go to that line and check what might be null at this point.
3. When you ask question, please add relevant code next time. People will be more than happy to help if you put more effort and provide more details.

Comment: Well... source code is in google code, it's too long, so i put them to google code.

Comment: Thank you, I bound music service twice causes this problem.